# $ \lim_{x\to o} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{ex^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-theorem

> $$ \lim_{x\to o} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{ex^2} $$

(can this be duplicate? I think not)
I tried it using many methods

$1.$ Solve this conventionally taking $1^\infty$ form in no luck

$2.$ Did this, expand $ {(1+x)^{\frac1x}}$ using binomial theorem got $\frac13$ then grouped coefficients of $x^0$ and it cancelled with $e$ then took coefficient of $x$ cancelled with $\frac{ex}{2}$ and so on
  [image: my steps] 
very messy right ? at last I got $\frac13$ but that's not the expected answer!

I must have went wrong somewhere can anyone help me with this.

Comment: trust me there are more pages to this but this page is most relevant

Comment: Is L'Hospital not allowed?

Comment: Use Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^{1/x}$ . You will get 11/24e

Comment: @Gokul do it but it will not work. It's IIT JEE Mock question

Comment: @user223679 I don't know what taylor expansion actually means can you elucidate

Comment: @PrasunBiswas:Doesn't this give $0/0$? I mean the numerator does come out to be 0 is you solve it?

Comment: Just put $(1 + x)^{1/x} = \exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}\right)$ cancel common factor $e$ from numerator and denominator. After that a simple manipulation with taylor/lhr is sufficient.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas You're wrong; l'Hôpital is applicable when the *limits* of numerator and denominator are both $0$ or both infinity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if I do that then e and e cancels then I get $\frac{ex/2}{ex^2}=\frac1{2x}$

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the correction! I have deleted my comment. :)

Comment: egreg exactly @Gokul notice that so L hopital isnt applicable

Comment: @user223679 can please post the answer as I think your consistent with the answer i have got

Comment: It is applicable. The first and second term cancel out. You get a $0/0$ form. It is very messy though.

Comment: @gokul are you sure you read the question properly as I can't see the possibility of l hopital rule but again if you're sure do post an answer I will be more than happy to accept it

Comment: @IlayaRajaS: It's [rather messy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2B1%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%29%27%27). Taylor expansions are better.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Consider dropping a visit [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-and-random-talk). Its about Indian High schoolers and JEE :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $y = \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n.$ taking logarithm, we get 
$$\begin{align} \ln y &= n\ln\left(1 + \frac 1n  \right)\\
           &=  n \left(\frac 1n - \frac1{2n^2}  +\frac1{3n^3}+\cdots \right)  \\
           & = 1 - \frac1{2n} + \frac{1}{3n^2}+ \cdots        \end{align}$$
therefore $$\begin{align} y &= ee^{-\frac1{2n}} e^{\frac1{3n^2}}\\
&=e\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+ \frac1{8n^2}+\cdots\right) 
\left(1+\frac{1}{3n^2}+\cdots\right) \\
&=e\left(1- \frac1{2n} +\frac{11}{24n^2} + \cdots\right)
\end{align}$$
from this we get $$n^2\left(y - e + \frac e{2n}\right) = \frac{11e}{24} + \cdots $$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1+ x)^{\frac1x}- e + \frac{ex}2}{ex} =\frac{11}{24}. $$

Comment: @abel very simple thank you

Comment: @IlayaRajaS, you are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Taylor expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) of $(1+x)^{1/x}$.

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=e(1- \frac{x}{2} + \frac{11x^2}{24} + ..........)$$

The other terms wont be required in this limit.

The numerator simplifies and the $x$ terms get cancelled out.

Comment: The thing is how do one get this series expansion.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I actually knew this expansion. The other answers are better than mine. They have sort of derived it.

Comment: So the Taylor expansion is another name for exponential expansion @user

Comment: @IlayaRajaS The Taylor Series is generalized stuff. Like, it can be used to get infinite series of $sin(x)$ too. Other answers use the expansion of $log(x)$ which in fact is a part of Taylor expansions IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{(1 + x)^{1/x} - e + \dfrac{ex}{2}}{ex^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}\right) - e + \dfrac{ex}{2}}{ex^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x} - 1\right) - 1 + \dfrac{x}{2}}{x^{2}}\text{ (cancelling }e\text{ from Nr and Dr)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(-\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + o(x^{2})\right) - 1 + \dfrac{x}{2}}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1 +\left(-\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + o(x^{2})\right) + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(-\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + o(x^{2})\right)^{2} + o(x^{2}) - 1 + \dfrac{x}{2}}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(-\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + o(x^{2})\right)^{2} + o(x^{2})}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{x^{2}}{3} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{8} + o(x^{2})}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{11x^{2}}{24} + o(x^{2})}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{11}{24}
\end{align}

Note that using Taylor series seems to be the only option as L'Hospital will only complicate the limit expression.

Comment: How is this answer different from Bernard's answer?

Comment: @user223679: I don't think it is significantly different from Bernard's. Its just that I got interrupted by something while typing the answer and later completed it.

Comment: Anyways I have upvoted all as I know how much effort must have went into this.

Answer (score 2):

$(1+x)^{\tfrac 1x}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln(1+x)}x}$, and $\,
\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}x =1-\dfrac x2+\dfrac{x^2}3+o(x^2)$, hence
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{\tfrac 1x}-\mathrm e+\frac{\mathrm ex}2&=\mathrm e\Bigl(\mathrm e^{-\tfrac x2+\tfrac{x^2}3+o(x^2)}\Bigr)\\
&=\mathrm e\frac{11x^2}{24}+o(x^2)
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\lim_{x\to o} \frac{(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-e+\dfrac{ex}{2}}{ex^2}=\lim_{x\to o}\frac{11}{24}+o(1)= \frac{11}{24}.$$