# Find the limit of the following.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \ 0}\frac{{(1+x)}^\frac{1}{x}-e+ex}{x^2}$$

Using Taylor Expansion, $(1+x)^{1/x}=e(1- \frac{x}{2} + \frac{11x^2}{24} + ...)$. Finally, I found that $$\lim_{x\to \ 0}\frac{{(1+x)}^\frac{1}{x}-e+ex}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to \ 0}\frac{\frac{ex}{2}+\frac{11ex^2}{24}+...}{x^2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \ 0}\frac{\frac{e}{2}+\frac{11ex}{12}+...}{x}$$

Now, It seems limit doesn't exist, but options are given for this question as

1) $\frac{11e}{12}$

2)$-\frac{11e}{12}$

3)$\frac{11e}{24}$

4)$-\frac{11e}{24}$. So How to proceed further?

Thank you.

Comment: HAs already been posted, see
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284801/lim-x-to-o-frac1x-frac1x-e-fracex2ex2/1284861#1284861

Comment: ^That's not quite the same problem. This has $ex$ not $\tfrac{ex}{2}$ in the numerator. Although that might be a mistake by the poster Chiranjeev.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 : There is no mistake. Question is same as i posted.

Comment: @Idris : now see i have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that as currently written, the limit does not exist. If the problem meant to ask $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \ 0}\frac{{(1+x)}^\frac{1}{x}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}$, then the answer would be $\dfrac{11e}{24}$, which is answer choice (3). My guess is that whoever wrote the question made a typo in writing $ex$ instead of $\frac{ex}{2}$ in the numerator.

Comment: yeah i also thinking that, so it should be printing mistake in the question paper.